# How to rename a file to include remote machine's hostname via batch script?

Tags: batch, batch-file, hostname, unc, computer-name

I have a .bat file that copies a file from one computer to another. During the transfer I would like to rename the file to include the hostname of the computer from which the file originated. The current rename code looks like this:

```
ren "\\remote-machine\c\Program Files\Applications\Applications.LOG" "%fullstamp%-%ComputerName%-Applications.LOG"**
```

The .bat file itself is run from the *destination* machine, so the `%ComputerName%` variable reflects the hostname of the destination computer, not the source machine. Is there a simple way to reflect the hostname of the source computer without having to transfer .bat files to that machine?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have to know the name of the remote computer in order to copy a file from it, use that information to name the file:

```
Set RemoteName=remote-machine
Ren "\\%RemoteName%\c\Program Files\Applications\Applications.LOG" "%fullstamp%-%RemoteName%-Applications.LOG"
```